# Load localized resources from custom location

Tags: c#, localization, modularity

In a c# application I have a resource file with English strings (`strings.resx`) and several localized versions of that (`strings.es.resx`, `strings.fr.resx`, etc.). When compiling, the base strings are included in the assembly, each extra localized resource file is compiled into a .dll file that is put in a folder named like the language code (e.g. `es/<appname>.resource.dll`).

So far I bundled all the localized dll files with the app. I guess most users only need at most one extra localized resource file, so I want to ship the app without the extra localized files and only download them if needed. Assuming the user installed the app in `program files` or another protected folder, I want to save the localized files in a folder in `%localAppData%`.

How do I load the localized resource file if they are not in the app folder? Currently they're all in the source folder `local/strings.resx`, `local/strings.es.resx`, etc. and I can load them with

```
        var rm = new ResourceManager("MyApplication.local.strings", typeof(Form1).Assembly);
```

to have the strings with the current `CultureInfo`.

I'd like to tell the app: load the strings but also check this specific folder (e.g. `%localAppData%/MyApplication/local`) for localized versions of that resource file.

Comment: Why not install them where they belong, but only on demand. At install time, ask the user what language(s) they'd like, and download them and install them in the right place. If they later learn Afrikaans and want that installed, they fire the installer back up and ask to modify the installation (this is kinda/sorta the Visual Studio model)

Comment: @Flydog57 That sounds like the right way, thanks. I hoped I could let the user choose a language in the options, and the app itself then downloads the file. Because of the possibly needed elevation that could cause issues, that's why I wanted to store the files in the localAppData.